# How to view Azure Application Insights (Local)?

Tags: azure

After adding Application Insights (Local) in Visual Studio, how do I view it? I can view the normal one which is not Local but I am not sure how to view the Local version.

[image]

Comment: Local version can be seen in the console output  of the app.

Comment: You need to add the Connection String of the Application Insights in the Configuration file.

Comment: how do I view all those monitoring like what I can see from Azure cloud service?

Comment: Are you able to see the logs now?

Answer (score 1):

Once you configure Application Insights Locally, `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` NuGet Package is installed and the below line of code is added in the `Program.cs` file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

- You need to add the Application Insights Connection String in `appsettings.json` file manually.

```cs
 "ApplicationInsights": {
   "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
 }
```

Once you run the app locally you can see the logs in Output console.

[image]

- This also can be seen in the Application Insights Resource in Portal.
- Change the configuration of `appsettings.Development.json` like below.

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://**.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://**.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Information Log on 6th Feb from Dev Env");
```

***Output in Transaction Search of Application Insights:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Steve - Any update on the logs